# Should I declare zone on slave server for DNS notify and zone transfer

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have problems with DNS notify and zone tranfer. My setup is as follow.

Master server: 10.90.7.10
Slave server 1: 10.90.7.11
Slave server 2: 10.90.7.12

I have started rndc server on slave server 1, but not on slave server 2. Upon a zone is created on master server, the master server will use rndc to create the zone declaration on slave 1, however slave server 2 is not declared for the created zone.

Next, when I add a record to the created zone on the master server, the master will send DNS notify to both the slave server 1 and slave server 2 on the zone changed. Both slave servers can receive the notify for the created zone. But the problem is that on slave server 2, there is an error reported as follow:

```
client 10.90.7.10#56488: received notify for zone 'foo.com': not authoritative
```

I guess the root cause may because of the non-existence of zone declaration for 'foo.com' on slave server 2. So I got the error only on slave server 2, but didn't get any errors on slave server 1.

Is my assumption correct? Should the zone be created on slave servers in prior to DNS notify and zone transfer?

I am a DNS newbie, looking forward to your answers!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ns records for foo.com for server1,2,3.

Define the zone on both slaves.

Increment the serial number on the master.

Comment: So, you mean zone foo.com must be created on slave servers to initiate DNS notify from master. At the same time, NS and SOA records must exist. Right?

Comment: @Jet Yes. If the slave servers would start accepting any DNS notify without the zone being created first, then any random person on the internet would be able to start using your servers as slaves without your knowledge.

Comment: But the server does not have to be in the zone with a NS record for it to work.